# Making multi-language ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, xcode4, multilingual

I need to build an app which will be multilingual. For instance, the app will be released in France and the Netherlands. The user needs to select a language when the app first start for the first time. Is there an easier way to do this?  In Xcode I saw something about localizations. Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/ - this is one tutorial.. there are many more.

Comment: Thnx! Was searching on the wrong keywords probably

Comment: Here another tutorial http://www.delitestudio.com/2012/09/11/how-to-internationalize-an-os-x-ios-app/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These are great resources for your localization efforts:

- Apple's own [Internationalization Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [How to Localize an iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) tutorial
- [Localization Guide for iPhone](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/)

Answer (score 22):

Xcode 6.0 :
           It provides wonderful features for [Internationalisation and Localisation.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) ("Localizing with Xcode 6" video). For quick usage I write some useful steps.

Step 1 :

click on project -> info -> scroll down -> localizations -> click on '+' and add your required language -> check as required -> Finish.

for xcode 6 : click on project -> change target to  -> info > scroll down -> localizations -> click on '+' and add your required language -> check as required -> Finish.

Step 2 :

click on 'Supporting Files' -> right click -> New File -> select Resource on left-side list -> select 'Strings Files' -> next -> name it 'Localizable' -> create

Step 3 :

click on newly created file -> go to Utilities -> file inspector -> click on 'Localize..' -> check all language

Step 4 :

open Localizable.strings(English)
   write 
   "help" = "I can't help you";

here "help" is a key 
         "I can't help you" is a value. You may change them as your wish.

open Localizable.strings(French) or the language you have set.
   write accordingly and you can translate "I can't help you" to any
   said language.

Step 5 :

```
// for test
NSString *str = NSLocalizedString(@"help", Nil);
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

We have done it.
You may check.

Now, to test goto settings of device -> general -> International -> language -> select said language or the language you have chosen (There are limited languages).
Run your app.
Hope this will help you. It help me.

Comment: Please share your pacific issue before downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading the [I18n docs](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/). You will never need to ask the user which language they use as this is obtainable through an API call, so you should do the smart thing and use whichever language they have preferred already on their device.

Comment: Problem with this is that the app will have an webshop. So if someone in the Netherlands uses French on his iPhone, orders will be placed in the French webshop. Which needs to the Dutch one off course. I agree it's not optimal but will have some thoughts about this.