# Internationalization in iOS app

Tags: ios6, internationalization, xcode4.5

I have to do Internationalization in iOS app.I searched and found **"genstrings"**.I have created **localizable strings** for the particular languages.

**My doubt is :** How to create an app to support all languages,instead of creating localizable strings for each language?

If any body has idea ,then please help me

Comment: If by "support" you mean "have translations for", there is really no way around it. Somebody needs to translate these strings and automatic translations are not good enough... BTW. There is much more to I18n than just make strings translatable...

Answer (score 1):

check these link
 [Making multi-language ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748600/making-multi-language-ios-app)
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000277-SW1

hope this will clear your doubts.